# Can replied email form email application (eg:gmail) be saved to web application database?

Tags: laravel, email

We have a custom CRM where we can send emails to clients. Email is sent to the reply-to email when the client replied to that email. I need to save the replied email content and attachments in the system database. Do you have any ideas on how we can implement this?

Comment: As vague as this question is so will be the answers. Get an IMAP-library, access your mails, save them in the database.

Comment: Solutions vary from: "Hire someone to open the email and copy/paste the contents in the database" to "Make AWS SES handle your reply to email address and use event bridge when an email event gets pushed to create a file on S3 and attach a lambda function to listen to when a file is created to S3 to save the contents of the file on a database" and a lot of ways in between.